# WebSphere 9.0 , EJB Deployment Error

Tags: ejb, websphere, ejb-3.0

While deploying EAR via HUDSON to Websphere 9.0

WebSphere throws following error

ADMA0205E: A validation error occurred in task Binding enterprise Bean to JNDI names. Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) names for the bean and its local/remote home are both specified for enterprise bean XXXXX in module XXXX. You can provide either JNDI name for the bean or JNDI names for its local/remote home.  But you cannot provide both.

can you please let me know if am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This normally indicates that the application has a problem in the `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` file. Specifically, for the bean XXXXX in module XXXX, there is a binding configuration that specifies both the `simple-binding-name` attribute and one of the following : `local-home-binding-name` or `remote-home-binding-name` attributes, or the `<interface>` element.  `simple-binding-name` is not compatible with these other attributes/element.

Information about the format of the `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` file is available here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html